# Error while select image from gallery and set as contact photo

Tags: android, image, performance, android-intent, uiimageview

while event is clicked. that open contact list. while one contact is select that its contain error.

> Enable To Load Photo

```
public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Context context= getApplicationContext();
                 Bitmap icon= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.id.photo);
                 try 
                 {  

                     Intent myIntent = new Intent();        
                     myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA); 
                     myIntent.setType("image/jpeg"); 
                     myIntent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpg");
                     myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, icon);
                     startActivity(myIntent); 

                 } 
                 catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
                 {  
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                     Log.i("ImageContact", 
                             "Firing Intent to set image as contact failed.", e);
                 }
            }
```

> this is my ActivityResult Method.

```
 if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                 try {
                     final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                     final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                     final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                     photo1.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change your line with this line

```
Bitmap icon= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.id.photo);
```

to

```
Bitmap icon= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.arrow1);
```

Comment: sorry, again contain same error. i didn't attach contact pic. ""Enable To Load Photo""

Comment: @Hiteshpatel just write the name of image in R.drawble.yourimage  ,it will work..it is working in my code.

Comment: when i select contact than only got message. ""Enable To Load Photo""

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844033/how-to-change-selected-contact-image-on-button-click-from-imageview   ckeck this link. this is my full code.

Comment: i approve becouse in your phon it is running.

Comment: ohk.. can u give me your mail id. i can send u my code for correction.

Comment: the code which i saw in ur that question is same as this question?so i post the whole source cod ehere..on that questuion

Answer (score 1):

You should change this

```
  Bitmap icon= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.id.photo);
```

To

```
  Bitmap icon= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.photo);
```

You go wrong over here `R.id.photo`.You need to access the drawable using `R.drawable.photo`.

**Update:** try this way

```
      Context context= getApplicationContext();
      Bitmap icon=    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.photo);

     Intent myIntent = new Intent();             
     myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA); 
     myIntent.setType("image/jpeg"); 
     myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, icon);
     startActivity(myIntent);
```

and also add

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

in your `manifest.xml`

Comment: its contain same Error. "enable to load photo"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844033/how-to-change-selected-contact-image-on-button-click-from-imageview

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your intent code :

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set as:"));
```